# pure rxjs if/else statement not reaching the else statement with merge

Tags: angular, rxjs

I try to write an if/else statement in pure rxjs with the user status sign in. In the case of the user is not signed in, I only keep the url to redirect after sign in.

The problem I face is that the url is not stored when the user is not connected.

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.initContactUsForm();

    const signedIn$ = this.authQuery.select(state => state.signedIn).pipe(share());

    const isSignedIn$ = signedIn$.pipe(
      filter((signedIn: boolean) => signedIn),
      switchMap((signedIn: boolean) => {
        this.isSignedIn = signedIn;
        this.userId = this.authQuery.getSnapshot().sub;
        return this.authService.currentAuthenticatedUser());
      })
    );

    const isNotSignedIn$ = signedIn$.pipe(
      filter((signedIn: boolean) => !signedIn),
      switchMap((signedIn: boolean) => {
        this.isSignedIn = signedIn;
        this.authService.storeAttemptedUrl(this.router.url);
        return empty();
      })
    )

    merge(isSignedIn$, isNotSignedIn$).subscribe(
      (user: any) => this.setContactUsFormSenderUserValues(user),
      (error: any) => console.log(error)
    )
  }
```

Am I missing something to get my url? What I am doing wrong?

Edit:
At first, I had this which is working. But I want it in pure observable style.

```
signedIn$.pipe(
  switchMap((signedIn: boolean) => {
    if (signedIn) {
      this.isSignedIn = signedIn;
      this.userId = this.authQuery.getSnapshot().sub;
      return this.authService.currentAuthenticatedUser();
    } else {
      this.isSignedIn = signedIn;
      const url = this.router.url;
      this.authService.storeAttemptedUrl(url);
      return empty();
    }
  }),
).subscribe(
  (user: any) => this.setContactUsFormSenderUserValues(user),
  (error: any) => console.log(error)
)
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I don't think there's anything wrong with your conditional version with the `if` inside the `switchMap`. Your function isn't pure anyways, so trying to write it in a pure observable style is going upstream.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problematic behavior. I observed that when merging my streams (here `isSignedId$` and `isNotSignedIn$`), the second stream input in merge (here `isNotSignedIn$`) would not start flowing.

Upon removing the `share()` operator on the source Observable (here `signedIn$`), this behavior changed, both streams merged would flow and my problem was solved.